# how to change the default text when creating a new html file in eclipse?

Tags: html, eclipse

When I create a eclipse file rightClick on project ->new-> html file then ,the eclipse creates a file without any indentations which is a silly problem. But I'm now practicing jsp and have to create as many as 40 files so I think it's time waste to correct indentations each time. Anybody please help me how to change the default text...For further clarity I have attached the image...Here is the image...[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the *second* page of the **New HTML File** or **New JSP File** wizards, you will see options for what the contents will be. There is also a link to the corresponding editor's Templates preference page, below the preview pane, where you can modify the provided options (such as to modify the formatting or add a copyright header) or make new options of your own.

The "new file" templates are also offered through Content Assist on empty files.

[image: The second page of the New JSP File wizard]

[image: Template preference pages, specifically the one for HTML files]